# Making a custom US forest topo map with R

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I am planning a hike, and of course by luck the trail I want to do is spread over 4 US forest topo sheets. So I am trying to make a single geotiff using the raster package in R.

```
# each file is about 15MB.

f1 <- 'http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/downloadMap.php?mapID=472212115&mapType=tif'
f2 <- 'http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/downloadMap.php?mapID=472212122&mapType=tif'
f3 <- 'http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/downloadMap.php?mapID=473012122&mapType=tif'
f4 <- 'http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/downloadMap.php?mapID=473012115&mapType=tif'
download.file(f1,destfile = '~/chikamin.tif',method='wget')
download.file(f2,destfile = '~/sno.tif',method='wget')
download.file(f3,destfile = '~/sno_l.tif',method='wget')
download.file(f4,destfile = '~/bsm.tif',method='wget')
require(raster)
require(spatial)
r1=raster('~/chikamin.tif')
r2=raster('~/sno.tif') 
r3=raster('~/sno_l.tif')
r4=raster('~/bsm.tif')
r1
tiled=extend(extend(extend(r1,r2),r3),r4)
tiled
plot(tiled)
```

but in my case the tiled map is only showing one of the original maps, and colors seems off. When I try the mosaic, it complains about the origins being different.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a rare case where I would use GDAL directly rather than via R, do gdalbuildvrt out.vrt chikamin.tif sno.tif sno_l.tif bsm.tif  then gdal_translate out.vrt merge.tif